# $\lim _{n\to\infty}\frac{\prod_{z^n=-1}P(z)^n}{\prod_{z^n=1}P(z)^n},$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to calculate the limit of the following quantity $$\lim _{n\to\infty}\frac{\prod_{z^n=-1}P(z)^n}{\prod_{z^n=1}P(z)^n},$$ where $P$ is a polynomial of one complex variable. I guess the limit is 1, but I don't know how to prove.

Some one can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your notation $\,z^n=\pm 1\,$ mean that the product must be taken over the $\;n$-th roots of $\,\pm 1\,\,$ in each case?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes it is.

Comment: In fact I wrote $P(z)=(z-z_1)...(z-z_k)$ where $z_1,...,z_k$ are roots of $P(z)$ ($k$ is degree of $P$). Then using the fact that $\prod_{z^n=s}(z_1-z)=z_1^n-s$, we are left with the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1})^n$$.

Comment: Can't you apply l'Hopital to the limit in the comment (after taking logs)?

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: I don't understand what you mean. I just know the l'hopital for the quantity of form $A(n)/B(n)$, but after taking log, we don't have that form. Can you explain more detail?

Answer (score 1):

If $z_1>1$, then given any $c>0$, we have $1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1}<1+\frac{c}{n}$ for large $n$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1})^n\le\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{c}{n})^n= e^c$. Let $c\to 0$, we obtain $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1})^n\le 1$, hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1})^n= 1$.

This is simply 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1})^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1})^{\frac{z_1^n-1}{2} \frac{2n}{z_1^n-1}}=e^0=1,
$$
which holds for $|z_1|>1$.

If $0<z_1<1$, $(1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1})^n=(-1)^n\bigg[1+\frac{2}{\frac{1}{z_1^n}-1}\bigg]^n$, which diverges.

So the limit might not exist.

Comment: Thanks to you! Additionally, can we do similar thing for the general case $z \in \mathbb{C}$? I am wandering what will happen for the case $|z|=1$.

Comment: @mapping87 The argument can be modified to show $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{z_1^n-1})^n=1$ if $|z_1|>1 $.